# How To: Auto Name Column when building a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I seen some answers that seemed close to my solution but they used code and I'd prefer to do this in SQL if I can. I know roughly what's needed but I have never seen anyone do this before in SQL. I'm building a table but I don't want to setup each column name by hand. The structure will be something similar to this:

```
ID - BIGINT - Primary Key - Seed Increment 1 start at 1
Email - NVARCHAR(500) do not allow null
Board_Name - NVARCHAR(100) - Do not allow null 
Tile_1 - BIT - Do Not Allow Null
Tile_2 - BIT - Do Not Allow Null
Tile_3 - BIT - Do Not Allow Null
Tile_4 - BIT - Do Not Allow Null
Tile_5 - BIT - Do Not Allow Null
Tile_6 - BIT - Do Not Allow Null
Tile_7 - BIT - Do Not Allow Null
Tile_8 - BIT - Do Not Allow Null
Tile_9 - BIT - Do Not Allow Null
Tile_10 - BIT - Do Not Allow Null
```

The table "Tile_X" I need to do this 348 times. So obviously I don't want to do that 348 times.

```
 DECLARE @X INT

 SET @X = 1

 WHILE (@X <=348)
 BEGIN
     PRINT @X
     SET @X = @X + 1

     ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Game_Board]
     ADD 'Tile_' + @X BIT NOT NULL;
 END
 GO
```

Gives error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
>   Incorrect syntax near 'Tile_'.

Update:
I already built the table but I did not add the Tile columns yet. So I need to figure out how to fix this loop to get it to add them.

Update:
Also tried this:

```
DECLARE @X INT
DECLARE @Column NVARCHAR(100)

SET @X = 1
SET @Column = 'Tile_' + @X

WHILE (@X <=348)
BEGIN
    PRINT @X    

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Game_Board]
    ADD @Column BIT NOT NULL;

    SET @X = @X + 1
    SET @Column = 'Tile_' + @X
END
GO
```

Get error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
>   Incorrect syntax near '@Column'.

Comment: You probably rather want a separate table for the tiles enumerating them and a foreign key to the board.

Comment: And you should tag the DBMS you're using as procedural syntax and capabilities varies quite a lot between them.

Comment: Google for first normal form.

Comment: Maybe I need to explain what this will be used for to help people better understand. Building a video game and the users progress will be stored in the database. Users will be able to reset the board at any point etc. So the table will change a lot. I'm sure their are better ways to build the table but just trying to build something i understand and its super basic to start. Then i'll branch off later and use better construction once i get it going.

Comment: Sounds a bit like trying to learn roofing on an old shed taking the risk to break through the roof while doing so... for whatever reason.

Comment: "The table will change a lot"!!! Stop right there. Your schema should not change at all. This is a major antipattern and it will set you in a direction of major pain (which you are already experiencing!). Consider a second table called `tiles` with the column: `id | tile_number | value`. Then you can grow in rows, not in new columns. Then in your original table above you have `id | email | board_name | tiles_id` where `tiles_id` corresponds to your `tiles.id` in your new second table. Remember... In a database we scale in rows, not in tables or columns. Set the schema once.

Comment: The database **contents** "change a lot", but the database **structure** should change only rarely.  Consider: in your design, you have to change your database structure just to add a tile.  You really want to create a `tiles` table, as @JNevill described.

Comment: 348 bit values represents a number between 0 and 2^348 - which is 5.733....e+104 - I'm pretty sure you don't need such a huge number of possibilities.

Comment: Thanks and yes I do need that. I'll just build this by hand until someone can post a answer.

Comment: Your getting the syntax error because when you use the plus operator to concatenate you have to make sure that both sides are strings or else it will try to add them.... you have to cast the variable to a string in this case varchar(length) or nvarchar(length)...ADD 'Tile_' + CAST(@X AS NVARCHAR(50))...but as others are telling you your design needs to follow a better pattern. Read about database design. What you need is not complicated at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use dynamic T-SQL as shown in the code below

```
DECLARE @X INT;
DECLARE @Column NVARCHAR(100);
SET @X = 1;
SET @Column = 'Tile_' + CAST(@X AS NVARCHAR(3));
DECLARE @tsql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)= '';
WHILE(@X <= 348)
    BEGIN
        SET @tsql = @tsql + ' ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Game_Board] '
        SET @tsql = @tsql + ' ADD ' + @Column + ' BIT NOT NULL;';
        SET @X = @X + 1;
        SET @Column = 'Tile_' + CAST(@X AS NVARCHAR(3));
    END;
--PRINT @tsql
EXEC sys.sp_executesql 
    @tsql;
GO
```

See also [sp_executesql (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)